SSRS Parameters Grayed Out for a Single User
We have SQL Server 2016 and SSRS to go with it.  I have a number of reports that work perfectly for about 70 users but 1 cannot use any of the report parameters.  She sees them but cannot choose anything as they are greyed out.
I tried both hard-coding the parameter choices and getting from query.
I also deleted and re-added one of the reports to no avail.
She can run/see the reports just cannot select a param.  The HTML clearly shows the select control as being disabled for that one user.
I also confirmed she is in all the same AD groups as all the other users and she is running the same version of Edge as all the other users.
Any ideas?

A few things to consider:

Could you please verify this user does not have enable any special Web browser extension?
Clear the browser cache and cookies for the affected user. Sometimes, old cache data can cause unexpected behavior.
Examine SSRS log files.
Try accessing the report via another browser (e.g., Chrome, Firefox) to see if it's a browser-specific issue. Usually, things work perfectly with FireFox but not with Edge or Chrome when I test on SSRS 2016.
Is the user behind the same proxy or using same network, or using a VPN?
Reset User Profile in SSRS.

